# How can I partition a database table every month?

Tags: database, oracle, cron, sh, sqlplus

Every month we got to partition a table for said month's transaction, and we want to automate this process, I'm thinking about using a crontab, but the problem lies in the fact that I need some parameters like date and partition table to do so.

This is a server running SunOS which I can't use a shell other than the default sh, which makes a bit painful to program a shell script to run the query, but nonetheless that's what I want.

This is how we partition our table:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEME.TABLE ADD PARTITION "NAME_201905"  VALUES LESS THAN
(TO_DATE('2019-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
  COMPRESS FOR OLTP LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TABLESPACE";
```

We need a way to execute that query every month and every parameter should match the current date.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Assuming you're using a recent version, could you just interval partition the table?

Comment: Definitely sounds like [interval partitioning (link)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1#interval_partitioning).

Comment: @JustinCave, since he use `SEGMENT CREATION ...` clause, it must be a recent Oracle release. As far as I remember interval partition was introduced in version 11.1 which is already out of (standard) support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create or alter table to have interval partition. This requirement will be taken care of automatically.

you can set interval of hour, day , week, month or year.

each time a new month's data comes Oracle automatically creates a new partition.